Transfer data from survey to DataBase, when companies have variable number of products using VBA
I have a survey like this. One Company may have 1 to 10 products and this number veries from company to company.
I would Like to transfer each company survey to a Base, when each product will take a row, and the company name will repeat for all products it sells.



Enterprise
Product
Quantity




Enterprise 1
Product 1
Qtty 1


Enterprise 1
Product 2
Qtty 2


Enterprise 2
Product 1
Qtty 1


Enterprise 2
Product 2
Qtty 2


Enterprise 2
Product 3
Qtty 3


Enterprise 2
Product 4
Qtty 4



In the Data Base I need something like this!
The code I used is this but its serves for a fixed number of products and I need for a variable number of products for different companies. I tried but I cant arrive to a satisfying results.
Public Sub Transfer_Data_frm()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim dados As Variant
Dim i As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB_Production").Select
Set ws = Sheets(2)


Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
ultimaLinha = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        dados = Array(Array( _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Cells(7, "C").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("E7").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("C12").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("N12").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("C30").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("K30").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("C67").Value, _ 
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("G67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("H67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("I67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("J67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("K67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("M67").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("C73").Value, _
          Worksheets("Questionário").Range("C76").Value, _
          Now()))

        
            ' Loop para lançar os dados na planilha
    For i = LBound(dados) To UBound(dados)
        ' Verificar se a célula está vazia e parar o loop se estiver
        'If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 1)) Then Exit For
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 1).Value = dados(i)(0) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 2).Value = dados(i)(1) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 3).Value = dados(i)(2) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 4).Value = dados(i)(3) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 5).Value = dados(i)(4) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 6).Value = dados(i)(5) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 7).Value = dados(i)(6) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 8).Value = dados(i)(7) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 9).Value = dados(i)(8) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 10).Value = dados(i)(9) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 11).Value = dados(i)(10) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 12).Value = dados(i)(11) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 13).Value = dados(i)(12) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 14).Value = dados(i)(13) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 15).Value = dados(i)(14) '
        ws.Cells(ultimaLinha + 1, 16).Value = dados(i)(15) '
        ultimaLinha = ultimaLinha + 1
    Next i

End Sub


In the Data Base I need something like this! Do you forget to upload expected output?

What is the purpose of that nested array?  There's no way for us to figure out what your input ranges look like or how to adjust this from a fixed to a variable number of entries.   What do all of those ranges in the array correspond to?
